# How I can I add audio to my ffmpeg cli

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to add audio to my ffmpeg cli bellow

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vf format=yuv420p http://localhost:8080/feed.ffm
```

**EDIT**

```
arecord -l

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC883 Analog [ALC883 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: ALC883 Alt Analog [ALC883 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And here is with -L

```
arecord -L

default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Front speakers
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Alt Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Alt Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Alt Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Alt Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: -f alsa, -acodec libmp3lame, -c:a libmp3lame

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide an audio input. Assuming you want the desktop/"what you hear"/"stereo mix" sound the easiest method is to use pavucontrol to select what you want to record, then use [PulseAudio input](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse) in `ffmpeg`.

## pavucontrol

See [Capturing desktop audio with ffmpeg for using pavucontrol](https://askubuntu.com/a/682793).

## Or use `pactl list sources`

If you don't want to use pavucontrol then list the audio sources with `pactl list sources`:

```
$ pactl list sources | grep monitor
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor
                device.class = "monitor"
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
                device.class = "monitor"
```

Then run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf format=yuv420p http://localhost:8080/feed.ffm
```

Comment: cannot open audio device hw:0 (Device or resource busy)
hw:0: Input/output error

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic That was just an example. You need to use the correct input name for your particular input. See the links in the answer.

Comment: Ok I read ALSA Wiki but I dont know how to select my audio device -i hw:0,2 does not work

Comment: I edited my question you can see output of arecord -l at end of my question

Comment: I tried -i hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0 but thats my mic

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic I don't know which device you want to get audio from.

Comment: From rear output on motherboard

Comment: here is my mic -f alsa -thread_queue_size 1024 -sample_rate 48000 -channels 2 -i hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic You want the "desktop" sound (the sound that you hear through your speakers or headphones)?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117313/discussion-between-slobodan-vidovic-and-llogan).

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic See updated answer.

Comment: I dont have anything under recording in pavucontrol, also I cant use `-f pulse -i default` Im geting an error `Unknown input format: 'pulse'`

Comment: `pactl list sources | grep monitor
 Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
  device.class = "monitor"`

`cannot open audio device alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor (No such file or directory)
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor: Input/output error`

Comment: Here is my command `ffmpeg -video_size 1680x1050 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -thread_queue_size 1024 -f alsa -thread_queue_size 1024 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor -f webm -r 25 -s 1280x800 -cluster_size_limit 2M -cluster_time_limit 5100 -content_type video/webm -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -crf 30 -g 125  -deadline good -threads 4 icecast://source:hackme@localhost:8000/live.webm`

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic As the [ffmpeg pulse documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse) states your ffmpeg needs to be compiled with `--enable-libpulse`. I'm guessing yours does not have `--enable-libpulse`